# Sage + Latex - How to change a font for axes label?

Tags: unicode, plot, sagetex

I use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) and LaTeX and when I do this:

```
\begin{sagesilent}
  p2 = list_plot(zip(H, f(5)), True, color='blue', axes_labels=[u'$H,$ км',u'$\mu, c$'])
  p2.fontsize(14)
\end{sagesilent}
```

and run `sage DIPLOM.sagetex.sage` I get this:

```
/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py:887: MathTextWarning: Font 'default' does not have a glyph for '\u043a' [U43a]
  MathTextWarning)
```

So how can I change a font name to use not only latin symbols?

Comment: SageTeX isn't a popular package. You should consider posting your question at [AskSage](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/?start_over=true) if you can't get an answer here. I suspect the answer is it can be done if you graph using matplotlib based on [this post](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1020/can-i-add-mathematical-formulas-to-a-plot) and the answer given by Shashank.

Comment: Isn't this more of a Python issue than a LaTeX issue?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/mathtext.html#custom-fonts suggests that this is pretty tricky even in matplotlib, but http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Russian-labels-without-LaTeX-td23202.html suggests it is possible.  And the same syntax *should* work in Sage...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - yes, this is really a Sage/matplotlib issue, though it is definitely the kind of thing likely to come up when trying to do plots in LaTeX.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue at the Sage/Python 'end'.